# Prove that $A, P, Q$ are collinear.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, contest-math, circles

Two circles $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$ intersect at $A, B$. An arbitrary line through $B$ meets $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$ at $C, D$ respectively. The points $E, F$ are chosen on $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$ respectively so that $CE = CB$, $BD = DF$. Suppose that $BF$ meets $\omega_1$ at $P$, and $BE$ meets $\omega_2$ at $Q$. Prove that $A, P , Q$ are collinear.

If you can show that $\angle QBP=\angle QAE$ Or $\angle  QPB=\angle QEA$ then you would be done because $ABPE$ is a cyclic quad.

Hints, suggestions and solutions would be appreciated.

Taken from the $4$th Iranian Geometry olympiad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\measuredangle CEB=\measuredangle EBC=\alpha$ and $\measuredangle PBE=\beta.$

Thus, $$\measuredangle PAB=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle PEB=\measuredangle EPP+\measuredangle PBE=2\alpha+\beta.$$
In another hand, $$\measuredangle BAQ=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle BFQ=180^{\circ}-(\measuredangle BFD+\measuredangle QFD)=$$
$$=180^{\circ}-(\measuredangle DBF+\measuredangle QBD)=180^{\circ}-(\alpha+\beta+\alpha)=180^{\circ}-(2\alpha+\beta)$$ and we are done!

Comment: How do you know $\angle PAB= 180 - \angle PEB$ ?

Comment: @Tyrone Because $EPAB$ is cyclic.

Comment: Wouldn’t that mean $\angle PEB=\angle PAB$? Because the angles are subtended from the same chord

Comment: @Tyrone We can assume that $A$ and $E$ are placed in the different sides respect to the line $PB$.

Comment: @Tyrone The case with $\measuredangle PEB=\measuredangle PAB$ is the same.

Answer (score 1):

All the red-marked angles are equal.

[image]

All the green-marked angles are equal. In particular, $\angle QAD = \angle CBQ$ because of exterior angle of a cyclic quadrilateral.

$\angle pink = \angle green - \angle QAB = \angle BAD = \angle red$. Result follows.